# Is it possible to migrate my g-suite gmail accounts to office 365 home?

Tags: email, migration, google-workspace-for-business

I bought Office 365 Home because I was using Dropbox and I wanted to switch to OneDrive because it was cheaper.

I used my hotmail account to sign up for it.

Now, I have two g-suite accounts for my e-mail, with two addresses, x@example.com and y@example2.com

I was wondering if it was possible to migrate them into my office365 so that I can use outlook.com instead of gmail.com

Unfortunately it seems extremely hard to find out exactly what office 365 does and if it supports this, or how I would even go about doing it.

I wonder if anyone can shed some light on it? If I can migrate my email as well, I can stop paying for g-suite. The only part of g-suite I actually use, is the e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 365 home?
That doesn't include email accounts.  But, you can create free @outlook.com email accounts.

If you want @example.com, where example.com is your own domain, you'll need to move the one of the business tiers for that, the lowest being O365 business premium.

https://products.office.com/en-us/compare-all-microsoft-office-products?activetab=tab:primaryr2

If you move your email accounts to Office 365, you'd be able to cancel g-suite.
Microsoft does offer an article on doing this, which is here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mailbox-migration/migrating-imap-mailboxes/migrate-g-suite-mailboxes

Comment: Thanks, I kept seeing references to having your own e-mail but I didn't realise it was business only.

Answer (score 0):

Essjae is right, you can convert your g-suite account for outlook account.

You can't convert these accounts directly, all you need to do is create a free outlook account for each account and convert them one by one.

Each account must also have an office license.